# Need to configure SSH key ? MAAS - JUJU

Tags: juju, maas

In this documentation: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html
It says "There is no need to explicitly add an SSH key to MAAS when using Juju; it will automatically put your public key on any hosts that it starts up"

A few lines downwards, it says: Adding an SSH key - While you’re still on the MAAS preferences page, add your SSH key by clicking Add SSH key. "

In my opinion the documentation first tell me that this is not needed, and then tell me to add SSH key.  So, is this just confusing or failure in documentation, or is it something I have not understood ?

Is there some way to report documentation issues to the people that make or edit this  ?

Answer (score 1):

The key you are entering in the preferences page is the key that will be added by juju to each of the units it creates.  Therefore, you do not need to explicitly log into each unit and add the the key, as juju has done for you.

The documentation is correct, even if it does not read well.  I agree it should be updated to be more explicit.